# Speed up calculation of a special 3-array possible?

Tags: r, performance, vectorization, rcpp, tensor

I would like to determine a 3-array R with dimensions (K,d,d) from two matrices A of dim (K,N) and X with dim (d,N) where K is small, d is moderate but N is large (see code example below for typical values). The formula for the array is

> R[k, i, j] = sum( A[k, ] * X[i, ] * X[j, ] ).

This array has to be calculated numerous times, so speed is of the essence. Hence, I would like to know what might be the most efficient way to compute this in R?

### My current approach

My current approach is found below as "current" along with the "naive" approach, which is unsurprisingly considerably slower.

```
library(microbenchmark)

K = 3
d = 20
N = 1e5

tt = microbenchmark(
  
  current = {
    for(krow in 1:K){
      tmp = X * matrix(A[krow,], d, N, byrow = TRUE)
      R[krow,,] = tmp %*% t(X)  
    }},
  
  naive = {
    for(krow in 1:K){
      for(irow in 1:d){
        for(jrow in 1:d){
          Ralt[krow, irow, jrow] = sum(A[krow,] * X[irow, ] * X[jrow,])
        }
      }
    }},

  check = "equal",
  
  setup = {
    A = matrix(runif(K*N), K, N)
    X = matrix(runif(d*N), d, N)
    R = array(0, dim = c(K, d, d))
    Ralt = array(0, dim = c(K, d, d))
  },
  times = 5
)

print(tt)
```

### Questions

- Do you see any way to improve upon this? For example, is it possible to use the fact that R is symmetric in the last two indices?
- Could I expect a substantial (>30%) improvement from implementing this in Rcpp?

Comment: `R[krow,,] = tcrossprod(tmp, X)` could slightly improve this. You don't want to implement your naive approach with Rcpp (e.g., without using the BLAS for the matrix operations). Maybe RcppEigen or RcppArmadillo might be worth a try but I'm not optimistic. Parallelization could be an option but not simply for the `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can transpose `t` the matrix to enable column subsetting, what is faster than row subsetting. And this allows auto repetition instead of creating a new matrix.

```
tX <- t(X)
tA <- t(A)
for(krow in 1:K){
    . <- tX * tA[,krow]
    R[krow,,] <- t(.) %*% tX
}
```

A variant might look like:

```
tX <- t(X)
tA <- t(A)
for(krow in 1:K) R[krow,,] <- crossprod(tX * tA[,krow], tX)
```

Where its possible to speed up `crossprod` e.g. by `Rfast::Crossprod` (Tanks to @jblood94 for the comment).

A Rcpp variant can look like (but is currently slower than the others):

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(r"(void mmul(Rcpp::NumericMatrix A, Rcpp::NumericMatrix X, Rcpp::NumericVector R, int K, int d) {
  int KD = d*K;
  for(int i=0; i < d; ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j < d; ++j) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector tmp = X(_,i) * X(_,j);
      for(int k=0; k < K; ++k) {
        R[k + i*K + j*KD] = sum(A(_,k) * tmp);
      }
    }
  }
} )")

mmul(t(A), t(X), R, K, d)
```

And one using Eigen:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

#include <omp.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void mmulE(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd X, Rcpp::NumericVector R, int n_cores) {
  Eigen::setNbThreads(n_cores);
  for(int k=0; k < A.cols(); ++k) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = X.cwiseProduct(A.col(k).replicate(1, X.cols() ));
    Eigen::MatrixXd D = C.transpose() * X;
    for(int i=0; i<D.size(); ++i) {
      R[i*A.cols()+k] = D(i);
    }
  }
}
)")

mmulE(t(A), t(X), R, 1)
```

---

```
library(microbenchmark)

K = 3
d = 20
N = 1e5

tt = microbenchmark(
  
  current = {
    for(krow in 1:K){
      tmp = X * matrix(A[krow,], d, N, byrow = TRUE)
      R[krow,,] = tmp %*% t(X)  
    }},
  
  GKi = {
      tX <- t(X)
      tA <- t(A)
      for(krow in 1:K){
          . <- tX * tA[,krow]
          R[krow,,] <- t(.) %*% tX
      }
  },

  crossp = {
      tX <- t(X)
      tA <- t(A)
      for(krow in 1:K) R[krow,,] <- crossprod(tX * tA[,krow], tX)
  },

  Rfast = {
    tX <- t(X)
    tA <- t(A)
    for(krow in 1:K) R[krow,,] <- Rfast::Crossprod(tX*tA[,krow], tX)
  },

  Rcpp = mmul(t(A), t(X), R, K, d),

  RcppE1C = mmulE(t(A), t(X), R, 1),
  RcppE2C = mmulE(t(A), t(X), R, 2),
  RcppE4C = mmulE(t(A), t(X), R, 4),

  check = "equal",
  
  setup = {
    A = matrix(runif(K*N), K, N)
    X = matrix(runif(d*N), d, N)
    R = array(0, dim = c(K, d, d))
  },
  times = 5
)

print(tt)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 current 106.44215 108.73900 161.66269 159.30184 216.37502 217.45546     5
     GKi  84.56926  87.98166 111.04126  90.18420  97.30869 195.16249     5
  crossp 112.02929 113.01796 113.67749 113.93593 114.49450 114.90976     5
   Rfast  39.12859  42.11124  45.42296  46.83398  49.46175  49.57924     5
    Rcpp 156.28284 156.38025 182.19358 157.05552 159.86193 281.38735     5
 RcppE1C  38.94770  40.49375  42.71140  40.69852  46.57995  46.83707     5
 RcppE2C  35.03088  35.67732  36.73970  36.52070  36.64065  39.82895     5
 RcppE4C  31.40532  33.94128  34.53725  34.40168  34.64187  38.29608     5
```

---

Maybe have also a look at:
[Crossprod slower than %*%, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721342)
[How to make crossprod faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744906)
[fast large matrix multiplication in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923787)

Comment: Good point!  But I had to test the ". <-" thing. This is soooo bad. ;- )

Comment: Your `tmp` should be and my `.` but transposed. So does `. <- t(tX * tA[,krow])` and then `Ralt[krow,,] <- . %*% tX` solve this for you?

Comment: Or just `for(krow in 1:K) Ralt[krow,,] <- crossprod(tX * tA[,krow], tX)`

Comment: @jblood94 Is there a difference to `for(krow in 1:K) Ralt[krow,,] <- crossprod(tX * tA[,krow], tX)` what is in the answer since about 3 hours?

Comment: As far as output, no, but curiously, `crossprod` is slower on my machine. I hadn't expected that, since from `?crossprod`: "This is formally equivalent to (but usually slightly faster than) the call t(x) %*% y".

Comment: Its also sower on my machine.

Comment: Ah, but `Rfast::Crossprod` is about 3 times as fast as `base::crossprod` in this case. Good to know. I'll note that in an answer.

Comment: @jblood94 In my case Rfast::Crossprod is slower. Maybe depends on cpu, libraries, ... Or I have done something wrong.

Comment: It very well could. If you ran the reprex in my answer, I don't see how you could have done something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'll point out that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76171162/9463489) can also be formulated using `crossprod`. `base::crossprod` turns out to be slower than even the OP's solution, but `Rfast::crossprod` is quite a bit faster *on my machine*. (This may be *very* machine dependent--see the comments).

```
library(Rfast)

K <- 3L
d <- 20L
N <- 1e5L

A <- matrix(runif(K*N), K, N)
X <- matrix(rnorm(d*N), d, N)
R <- Ralt <- R2 <- array(0, c(K, d, d))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  current = {
    for(krow in 1:K){
      tmp = X * matrix(A[krow,], d, N, byrow = TRUE)
      R[krow,,] = tmp %*% t(X)  
    }},
  
  GKi = {
    tX <- t(X)
    tA <- t(A)
    for(krow in 1:K){
      . <- tX * tA[,krow]
      Ralt[krow,,] <- t(.) %*% tX
    }
  },
  
  Rfast = {
    tX <- t(X)
    tA <- t(A)
    for(krow in 1:K) R2[krow,,] <- Crossprod(tX*tA[,krow], tX)
  },
  
  crossprod = {
    tX <- t(X)
    tA <- t(A)
    for(krow in 1:K) R2[krow,,] <- crossprod(tX*tA[,krow], tX)
  },
  
  check = "equal",
  times = 20
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#>    current 124.9811 128.45265 146.73105 134.95665 166.8852 196.2118    20
#>        GKi 107.1674 143.01505 146.52661 149.23875 159.0276 184.7026    20
#>      Rfast  48.3825  52.84555  66.34697  55.43765  87.9278 108.8123    20
#>  crossprod 142.2860 147.58070 166.17528 155.26045 185.6892 220.4082    20
```

Comment: Yes its also here the same when I run your code. I get for Rfast `1116ms` while for crossprod `171ms`, current `188ms` and Gki `138ms`.

Comment: Good to know. I updated the answer to point out that it may be very machine-dependent.

Comment: Now I have done the same on a newer Computer and get for Rfast `41ms` while for crossprod `113ms`, current `117ms` and Gki `87ms`.

Comment: ```Rfast::Crossprod``` uses parallel for speeding the calculation. So, the execution time depends on the architecture. The newer machine the faster results.